# Unable to use Facebook SignIn from Capacitor.js for Web

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, facebook-javascript-sdk, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Good day,

I'm trying to implement Facebook SignIn to my Capacitor JS web app - But FB App Settings require that all calls be made from a secure HTTPS connection. However, Capacitor JS connect to http://localhost by default.

I've tried researching, but I've not found any solutions/workarounds. Has anyone else faced this problem? Pointers to possible solutions would be appreciated.

I've posted this issue [here](https://github.com/capacitor-community/facebook-login/issues/131) as well.

Thank you.